# Is it possible to detect a HTML video playing on a browser?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video

I want to know if a html video is being displayed on a browser, from outside said browser, ideally without any plugins or such.

Motivation - I am trying to add this feature to [Caffeine](https://launchpad.net/caffeine) which is a Linux utility which disables the OS screensaver if, say, you are watching a movie.

The flash support was done I believe by detecting the presence of particular files or folders created by the plugin.

Ideally I would like 1 solution, but if I get 2 solutions for Firefox and Chrome, that's good enough.

p.s. Ultimately this would involve python code, but I am not sure if that is sufficient to make this question on-topic, or if this belongs on Superuser or Unix&Linux

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of something a web browser I was building in VB .Net which needed to detect if there where web pages that had tags like `<a href="tel: or <a href="sms`I know you said you didn't want a plugin but I would think you could easily right a browser plugin for for just this. In fact not exactly what your looking for but theirs a script monkey script called [Hangouts Unlimited](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/131680) which prevents you from getting annoying messages asking if your still awake while in a G+ hangout. I don't know much about python but I would recomennd trying to identify the elements of the  tags and when ever it finds such tags to disable the screen saver. Obviously the hangouts unlimited doesn't affect the web browser and that is most likely why you prefer not to have a browser plugin because you need to access system files outside of the browser. But I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid a plugin is partly because I want an easy fix :(, partly because the project itself seems to have languished, and partly because the program itself is a seperate .. program, so companion plugins just make setup harder..

Comment: Here's some sudo code for you if <video exists then disable screensaver.